# "Symbol's function definition is void: cl-defstruct" error for my emacs script

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to write an emacs script to call from the command line in the following way:

```
emacs --script script.el
```

I am running into issues when I try to include either a `cl-defstruct` or a `defstruct` in said script. For example, the following works just fine when I run it in emacs using `M-x eval-buffer` but fails when run as a script:

```
(cl-defstruct test slot)
(setq myTest (make-test))
(setf (test-slot myTest) "hello")
(message (test-slot myTest))
```

The above should only spit out the the message "hello" but when run as a script, I see the following error:

```
Loading 00debian-vars...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...
Loading debian-ispell...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-default.el (source)...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50python-docutils.el (source)...
Symbol's function definition is void: cl-defstruct
```

The last line is particularly surprising. Any ideas why the cl-defstruct macro would not be recognized in this setting? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `(require 'cl-lib)` at the top of your script.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I had actually tried `(require 'cl)` and that did not work so I posted this.